# How to update neo4j procedure without downtime

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j

I have a java app that communicates with neo4j instance deployed in docker. Also, I have custom procedures placed at /plugins volume as a jar file.

According to docs, if I want to update the existing procedure or add a new one I should generate a new jar file, copy it into /plugins, and restart the instance. But the database will be available for some time.

How can I update neo4j procedure without downtime?

I guess what I can do is create a cluster from several instances of neo4j, and restart them one by one to avoid downtime. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes, we do this process 1) deploy the new APOC in each cluster 2) restart the instances one at a time. Another solution is to create a green/blue environment. But the idea is similar to the former.